# CakePHP how to define two of the same models through another join table with hasMany through

Tags: cakephp, has-many-through

I would like to use `hasMany through` relationship to connect two `users` through a model `invitations`

I currently have the following controller:

```
class User extends AppModel { 
var $name = 'User';
var $displayField = 'username';

var $hasMany = array(

    'Invitation' => array(
        'className' => 'Invitation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Invitation' => array(
        'className' => 'Invitation',
        'foreignKey' => 'receiver_user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
    )
}
```

However, when i get error:

```
Error: Database table sender_users for model SenderUser was not found.
```

Which is a bit annoying, because I already thought I specified that I want to use `Invitation`.

What is the issue, what code do I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you can't create the same association twice. Even from a PHP syntax perspective that's not possible. You'll have to give each association a unique name:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'SentInvitation'     => array(...),
    'ReceivedInvitation' => array(...)
);
```

Second, the problem is *probably* that you don't have an Invitation model. Cake creates a model on-the-fly according to naming conventions. Since you have a column `sender_user_id`, according to naming conventions you should therefore also have a `sender_users` table. Create the Invitation model and set it up without that association, then Cake shouldn't be looking for it.

Comment: Yes, that helped. Also, the autogenerated MODEL in the Invitations model had `'className' => 'SenderUser',` instead of `'className' => 'User',`. all good now :)